# Google apps script timing out when triggered programmatically, but runs within seconds when triggered manually

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a simple Google Apps script I'm working on to convert column 4 in my google sheet to a date field. I'd like for this to run each time my data uploads into the sheet, around 4am. currently the script works great when triggered to run manually, it runs within 4 seconds, but when it is scheduled via time-based trigger it hits the 6m threshold and times out. what are some ways I can get passed this?

This is what I've tried:

```
function FixDate1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('[Export Here]');

  var columnToConvert = 4; // Column D
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var rangeToConvert = sheet.getRange(1, columnToConvert, lastRow);

  var data = rangeToConvert.getValues(); // Get all values at once

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    // Perform any data processing or transformation here
    data[i][0] = new Date(data[i][0]); // Assuming column contains date strings

  }

  rangeToConvert.setValues(data); // Set all values at once
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Would you be able to provide your sample sheet [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can further help you?

Answer (score 0):

I ran it like this and it just takes a couple of seconds in manual and maybe 3 or 4 with the trigger.  I'm not surprised the trigger takes some time to find the function.  And nothing run's instantly on a shared server.

```
function FixDate1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  sh.getRange(1,4,sh.getLastRow()).setValue(new Date());
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Cooper! How did you test it using the trigger? I can never get it to run when I want

Comment: I just used ScriptApp.newTrigger() and created a trigger with the name FixDate1